# String inside a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a problem with a data, and I must read a text file that contains data from a list of lists.

```
with open('ej11.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

To read the file correctly I must eliminate the **first two elements ['** and **the last two ']**. I have tried with the "pop" method, but by doing so all data are eliminated.

Is there any practical way of being able to solve this? Thanks.

My data is like this:

```
["[[[1, 21, 13, 14, 15, 0.0, 3.0, 'W'], [2, 24, 16, 17, 18, 4.0, 3.0, 'W']], 8, 2]"]
```

My data should be like this:

```
[[[1, 21, 13, 14, 15, 0.0, 3.0, 'W'], [2, 24, 16, 17, 18, 4.0, 3.0, 'W']], 8, 2]
```

Comment: First of all, `.readlines()` is silly on a file with only one line - `.read()` would give you the string directly, without it being uselessly contained in a list.  `ast.literal_eval()` would then be the safest way to turn that string into actual Python objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

d = ["[[[1, 21, 13, 14, 15, 0.0, 3.0, 'W'], [2, 24, 16, 17, 18, 4.0, 3.0, 'W']], 8, 2]"]
data = ast.literal_eval(d[0])
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 21, 13, 14, 15, 0.0, 3.0, 'W'], [2, 24, 16, 17, 18, 4.0, 3.0, 'W']],
 8,
 2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution, it served me a lot. @Scott Boston